# Julia: Calling GSL functions

Tags: c, julia, gsl, scientific-computing

I'm trying to integrate a simple function in Julia using the GSL numerical integration function QNG. The form of the function in C is given as

```
int gsl_integration_qng (const gsl_function * f, double a, double b,
 double epsabs, double epsrel, double * result, double * abserr, size_t * neval)
```

I am trying to perform the following integration

```
f(x) = x^2
a, b, epsabs, epsrel = 0.0, 1.0, 1.0e-2, 1.0e-2
result, abserr = 0.0, 0.0
neval =  0x123456789abcdef
0x0123456789abcdef
t = ccall( (:gsl_integration_qng, "libgsl"), Int32, 
(Ptr{Void}, Float64, Float64, Float64, Float64, Ptr{Float64}, Ptr{Float64},Csize_t), 
  &f, a, b, epsabs, epsrel, &result, &abserr, neval)
```

I appreciate any assitance.

Comment: See https://github.com/jiahao/GSL.jl which has this function wrapped already.

Comment: Thanks a mil. Still haven't gotten it working, but this is at least an easier place to start.

Comment: @JohnDuffy Please mark one of the answers to the questions as the solution so this does not show up as unanswered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[I wrote a blog post awhile ago on how to do this](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/using-julias-c-interface-utilize-c-libraries/) on a different GSL integration function.

The gist of it is:

Define a parametrically typed function

```
function integrand{T,T2,T3}(x::T,dim::T2,params::T3)
  A = 1.0 / (pi * pi * pi)
  return A / (1.0 - cos(unsafe_load(x,1))*cos(unsafe_load(x,2))*cos(unsafe_load(x,3)))::Cdouble
end
```

Then get the pointer

```
integrand_c = cfunction(integrand,Cdouble,(Ptr{Cdouble},Ptr{Cdouble},Ptr{Cdouble}))
```

and then `ccall` the GSL function with the function pointer as one of the arguments. In my example:

```
ccall((:monte_carlo_integrate,"/home/crackauc/Public/libMonte.so"),Int32,(Ptr{Void},Ptr{Cdouble},Ptr{Cdouble},Int32,Int32,Ptr{Cdouble},Ptr{Cdouble},Csize_t),integrand_c,x,y,mode,dim,xl,xu,calls)
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of thought and looking at the existing GSL functions I got this working.

```
type gsl_function
    function_::Ptr{Void}
    params::Ptr{Void}
end

function function_callback(x::Cdouble, f_::Ptr{Void})
    f = unsafe_pointer_to_objref(f_)::Function
    convert(Cdouble, f(x))::Cdouble
end

const function_callback_ptr = cfunction(function_callback, Cdouble, (Cdouble, Ptr{Void}))

function integration_qng(f,a,b,epsrel,epsabs)
  result = convert(Ptr{Cdouble}, Array(Cdouble, 1))
  abserr = convert(Ptr{Cdouble}, Array(Cdouble, 1))
  neval = convert(Ptr{Csize_t}, Array(Csize_t, 1))
  t = ccall( (:gsl_integration_qng, :libgsl), Cint, (Ptr{gsl_function}, Cdouble, Cdouble, Cdouble, Cdouble, Ptr{Cdouble}, Ptr{Cdouble}, Ptr{Csize_t}), 
  &gsl_function(function_callback_ptr, pointer_from_objref(f)), a, b, epsabs, epsrel, result, abserr, neval )
  return unsafe_load(result)
end

f(x) = x^2
a = 0
b = 1
epsabs = 0
epsrel = 1e-2

println(integration_qng(f,a,b,epsrel,epsabs))
```

Also see here http://julialang.org/blog/2013/05/callback/ for a discussion about this kind of thing from someone more qualified than I.